# JS XML Parsing : differences in behavior depending on the browser?

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing, browser

please, I block on that Pb since few days :

i have a js var which contain an XML well formatted string (controled whith some online validators)

The Problem is with that js script :

```
                var amountOfNodes = 0;
                parser = new DOMParser();
                xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(XmlString , "text/xml");
                var nodes = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("identifiant");
                amountOfNodes = nodes.length;
```

With **Chrome its always OK** and i get the good amountOfNodes with no error and i can loop inside,

but with other browers **FF / IE / Edge** ..., i get an error into the console :

```
XML parsing error: not well formatted
Line number 1, Column 34229
```

so i cant get nodes  and loop inside the xml String.

Thanks for your advises

ps : that string XmlString  (but I truncated the file, because it is a little long) :

```
<racine>
<listepointretraitacheminement>
    <accespersonnemobilitereduite>false</accespersonnemobilitereduite>
    <adresse1>1 RUE DE LA GENDARMERIE</adresse1>
    <adresse2></adresse2>
    <adresse3></adresse3>
    <codepostal>17220</codepostal>
    <congespartiel>false</congespartiel>
    <congestotal>false</congestotal>
    <coordgeolocalisationlatitude>46.127996</coordgeolocalisationlatitude>
    <coordgeolocalisationlongitude>-1.009623</coordgeolocalisationlongitude>
    <distanceenmetre>24</distanceenmetre>
    <horairesouverturedimanche>00:00-00:00 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturedimanche>
    <horairesouverturejeudi>09:00-12:00 14:30-16:30</horairesouverturejeudi>
    <horairesouverturelundi>13:30-16:30 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturelundi>
    <horairesouverturemardi>09:00-12:00 14:00-16:30</horairesouverturemardi>
    <horairesouverturemercredi>09:00-12:00 14:00-16:30</horairesouverturemercredi>
    <horairesouverturesamedi>09:00-12:00 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturesamedi>
    <horairesouverturevendredi>09:00-12:00 14:00-16:30</horairesouverturevendredi>
    <identifiant>171940</identifiant>
    <indicedelocalisation></indicedelocalisation>
    <localite>LA JARRIE</localite>
    <nom>BUREAU DE POSTE LA JARRIE BP</nom>
    <periodeactivitehorairedeb>04/11</periodeactivitehorairedeb>
    <periodeactivitehorairefin>31/12</periodeactivitehorairefin>
    <poidsmaxi>20000</poidsmaxi>
    <typedepoint>BPR</typedepoint>
    <codepays>FR</codepays>
    <langue>FR</langue>
    <libellepays>FRANCE</libellepays>
    <loanofhandlingtool>false</loanofhandlingtool>
    <parking>false</parking>
    <reseau>R01</reseau>
    <distributionsort></distributionsort>
    <lotacheminement></lotacheminement>
    <versionplantri></versionplantri>
</listepointretraitacheminement>
<listepointretraitacheminement>
    <accespersonnemobilitereduite>false</accespersonnemobilitereduite>
    <adresse1>RUE DE LA PROVIDENCE</adresse1>
    <adresse2></adresse2>
    <adresse3></adresse3>
    <codepostal>17220</codepostal>
    <congespartiel>false</congespartiel>
    <congestotal>false</congestotal>
    <coordgeolocalisationlatitude>46.127199</coordgeolocalisationlatitude>
    <coordgeolocalisationlongitude>-1.003798</coordgeolocalisationlongitude>
    <distanceenmetre>481</distanceenmetre>
    <horairesouverturedimanche>00:00-00:00 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturedimanche>
    <horairesouverturejeudi>08:30-12:30 14:30-19:30</horairesouverturejeudi>
    <horairesouverturelundi>08:30-12:30 14:30-19:30</horairesouverturelundi>
    <horairesouverturemardi>08:30-12:30 14:30-19:30</horairesouverturemardi>
    <horairesouverturemercredi>08:30-12:30 14:30-19:30</horairesouverturemercredi>
    <horairesouverturesamedi>08:30-19:30 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturesamedi>
    <horairesouverturevendredi>08:30-19:30 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturevendredi>
    <identifiant>103882</identifiant>
    <indicedelocalisation></indicedelocalisation>
    <localite>LA JARRIE</localite>
    <nom>INTERMARCHE</nom>
    <periodeactivitehorairedeb>01/01</periodeactivitehorairedeb>
    <periodeactivitehorairefin>31/12</periodeactivitehorairefin>
    <poidsmaxi>20000</poidsmaxi>
    <typedepoint>A2P</typedepoint>
    <codepays>FR</codepays>
    <langue>FR</langue>
    <libellepays>FRANCE</libellepays>
    <loanofhandlingtool>false</loanofhandlingtool>
    <parking>false</parking>
    <reseau>R03</reseau>
    <distributionsort>79S44</distributionsort>
    <lotacheminement>NIT0</lotacheminement>
    <versionplantri>3</versionplantri>
</listepointretraitacheminement>
<listepointretraitacheminement>
    <accespersonnemobilitereduite>false</accespersonnemobilitereduite>
    <adresse1>5 RUE DU ROULLET</adresse1>
    <adresse2></adresse2>
    <adresse3></adresse3>
    <codepostal>17220</codepostal>
    <congespartiel>false</congespartiel>
    <congestotal>false</congestotal>
    <coordgeolocalisationlatitude>46.105072</coordgeolocalisationlatitude>
    <coordgeolocalisationlongitude>-1.054278</coordgeolocalisationlongitude>
    <distanceenmetre>4268</distanceenmetre>
    <horairesouverturedimanche>08:00-12:30 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturedimanche>
    <horairesouverturejeudi>07:30-13:30 16:30-20:00</horairesouverturejeudi>
    <horairesouverturelundi>00:00-00:00 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturelundi>
    <horairesouverturemardi>07:30-13:30 16:30-20:00</horairesouverturemardi>
    <horairesouverturemercredi>07:30-13:30 16:30-20:00</horairesouverturemercredi>
    <horairesouverturesamedi>08:30-20:00 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturesamedi>
    <horairesouverturevendredi>07:30-13:30 16:30-20:00</horairesouverturevendredi>
    <identifiant>999330</identifiant>
    <indicedelocalisation></indicedelocalisation>
    <localite>SALLES SUR MER</localite>
    <nom>TABAC CAFE DU CENTRE</nom>
    <periodeactivitehorairedeb>01/01</periodeactivitehorairedeb>
    <periodeactivitehorairefin>31/12</periodeactivitehorairefin>
    <poidsmaxi>20000</poidsmaxi>
    <typedepoint>A2P</typedepoint>
    <codepays>FR</codepays>
    <langue>FR</langue>
    <libellepays>FRANCE</libellepays>
    <loanofhandlingtool>false</loanofhandlingtool>
    <parking>false</parking>
    <reseau>R03</reseau>
    <distributionsort>79S44</distributionsort>
    <lotacheminement>NIT0</lotacheminement>
    <versionplantri>3</versionplantri>
</listepointretraitacheminement>
<listepointretraitacheminement>
    <accespersonnemobilitereduite>false</accespersonnemobilitereduite>
    <adresse1>78 RUE NATIONALE</adresse1>
    <adresse2></adresse2>
    <adresse3></adresse3>
    <codepostal>17220</codepostal>
    <congespartiel>false</congespartiel>
    <congestotal>false</congestotal>
    <coordgeolocalisationlatitude>46.129805</coordgeolocalisationlatitude>
    <coordgeolocalisationlongitude>-1.072773</coordgeolocalisationlongitude>
    <distanceenmetre>4848</distanceenmetre>
    <horairesouverturedimanche>09:30-13:00 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturedimanche>
    <horairesouverturejeudi>09:30-12:30 15:30-19:30</horairesouverturejeudi>
    <horairesouverturelundi>09:30-12:30 15:30-19:30</horairesouverturelundi>
    <horairesouverturemardi>09:30-12:30 15:30-19:30</horairesouverturemardi>
    <horairesouverturemercredi>09:30-12:30 15:30-19:30</horairesouverturemercredi>
    <horairesouverturesamedi>09:30-12:30 15:30-19:30</horairesouverturesamedi>
    <horairesouverturevendredi>09:30-12:30 15:30-19:30</horairesouverturevendredi>
    <identifiant>998778</identifiant>
    <indicedelocalisation></indicedelocalisation>
    <localite>LA JARNE</localite>
    <nom>BULLES DE FLEURS</nom>
    <periodeactivitehorairedeb>01/01</periodeactivitehorairedeb>
    <periodeactivitehorairefin>31/12</periodeactivitehorairefin>
    <poidsmaxi>20000</poidsmaxi>
    <typedepoint>A2P</typedepoint>
    <codepays>FR</codepays>
    <langue>FR</langue>
    <libellepays>FRANCE</libellepays>
    <loanofhandlingtool>false</loanofhandlingtool>
    <parking>false</parking>
    <reseau>R03</reseau>
    <distributionsort>79S44</distributionsort>
    <lotacheminement>NIT0</lotacheminement>
    <versionplantri>3</versionplantri>
</listepointretraitacheminement>
<listepointretraitacheminement>
    <accespersonnemobilitereduite>false</accespersonnemobilitereduite>
    <adresse1>ROUTE NATIONALE 137</adresse1>
    <adresse2></adresse2>
    <adresse3></adresse3>
    <codepostal>17690</codepostal>
    <congespartiel>false</congespartiel>
    <congestotal>false</congestotal>
    <coordgeolocalisationlatitude>46.11099</coordgeolocalisationlatitude>
    <coordgeolocalisationlongitude>-1.105416</coordgeolocalisationlongitude>
    <distanceenmetre>7601</distanceenmetre>
    <horairesouverturedimanche>00:00-00:00 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturedimanche>
    <horairesouverturejeudi>08:30-19:00 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturejeudi>
    <horairesouverturelundi>08:30-19:00 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturelundi>
    <horairesouverturemardi>08:30-19:00 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturemardi>
    <horairesouverturemercredi>08:30-19:00 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturemercredi>
    <horairesouverturesamedi>08:30-19:00 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturesamedi>
    <horairesouverturevendredi>08:30-19:00 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturevendredi>
    <identifiant>105170</identifiant>
    <indicedelocalisation></indicedelocalisation>
    <localite>ANGOULINS</localite>
    <nom>CARREFOUR</nom>
    <periodeactivitehorairedeb>01/01</periodeactivitehorairedeb>
    <periodeactivitehorairefin>31/12</periodeactivitehorairefin>
    <poidsmaxi>20000</poidsmaxi>
    <typedepoint>A2P</typedepoint>
    <codepays>FR</codepays>
    <langue>FR</langue>
    <libellepays>FRANCE</libellepays>
    <loanofhandlingtool>false</loanofhandlingtool>
    <parking>false</parking>
    <reseau>R03</reseau>
    <distributionsort>79S41</distributionsort>
    <lotacheminement>NIT0</lotacheminement>
    <versionplantri>3</versionplantri>
</listepointretraitacheminement>
<listepointretraitacheminement>
    <accespersonnemobilitereduite>false</accespersonnemobilitereduite>
    <adresse1>19 RUE DE LA GARE</adresse1>
    <adresse2></adresse2>
    <adresse3></adresse3>
    <codepostal>17440</codepostal>
    <congespartiel>false</congespartiel>
    <congestotal>false</congestotal>
    <coordgeolocalisationlatitude>46.133888</coordgeolocalisationlatitude>
    <coordgeolocalisationlongitude>-1.113055</coordgeolocalisationlongitude>
    <distanceenmetre>7974</distanceenmetre>
    <horairesouverturedimanche>09:30-13:00 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturedimanche>
    <horairesouverturejeudi>09:30-13:00 15:00-20:00</horairesouverturejeudi>
    <horairesouverturelundi>00:00-00:00 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturelundi>
    <horairesouverturemardi>09:30-13:00 15:00-20:00</horairesouverturemardi>
    <horairesouverturemercredi>09:30-13:00 15:00-20:00</horairesouverturemercredi>
    <horairesouverturesamedi>09:30-13:00 15:00-20:00</horairesouverturesamedi>
    <horairesouverturevendredi>09:30-13:00 15:00-20:00</horairesouverturevendredi>
    <identifiant>005787</identifiant>
    <indicedelocalisation></indicedelocalisation>
    <localite>AYTRE</localite>
    <nom>LA CAVE ROSE ROUGE ET BLANC</nom>
    <periodeactivitehorairedeb>01/01</periodeactivitehorairedeb>
    <periodeactivitehorairefin>31/12</periodeactivitehorairefin>
    <poidsmaxi>20000</poidsmaxi>
    <typedepoint>A2P</typedepoint>
    <codepays>FR</codepays>
    <langue>FR</langue>
    <libellepays>FRANCE</libellepays>
    <loanofhandlingtool>false</loanofhandlingtool>
    <parking>false</parking>
    <reseau>R03</reseau>
    <distributionsort>79S26</distributionsort>
    <lotacheminement>NIT0</lotacheminement>
    <versionplantri>3</versionplantri>
</listepointretraitacheminement>
<listepointretraitacheminement>
    <accespersonnemobilitereduite>false</accespersonnemobilitereduite>
    <adresse1>AVENUE EDMOND GRASSET</adresse1>
    <adresse2></adresse2>
    <adresse3></adresse3>
    <codepostal>17690</codepostal>
    <congespartiel>false</congespartiel>
    <congestotal>false</congestotal>
    <coordgeolocalisationlatitude>46.106096</coordgeolocalisationlatitude>
    <coordgeolocalisationlongitude>-1.108722</coordgeolocalisationlongitude>
    <distanceenmetre>7997</distanceenmetre>
    <horairesouverturedimanche>00:00-00:00 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturedimanche>
    <horairesouverturejeudi>09:00-12:00 14:30-16:45</horairesouverturejeudi>
    <horairesouverturelundi>09:00-12:00 14:00-16:45</horairesouverturelundi>
    <horairesouverturemardi>09:00-12:00 14:00-16:45</horairesouverturemardi>
    <horairesouverturemercredi>09:00-12:00 14:00-16:45</horairesouverturemercredi>
    <horairesouverturesamedi>09:00-12:00 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturesamedi>
    <horairesouverturevendredi>09:00-12:00 14:00-16:45</horairesouverturevendredi>
    <identifiant>170100</identifiant>
    <indicedelocalisation></indicedelocalisation>
    <localite>ANGOULINS</localite>
    <nom>BUREAU DE POSTE ANGOULINS BP</nom>
    <periodeactivitehorairedeb>04/11</periodeactivitehorairedeb>
    <periodeactivitehorairefin>31/12</periodeactivitehorairefin>
    <poidsmaxi>20000</poidsmaxi>
    <typedepoint>BPR</typedepoint>
    <codepays>FR</codepays>
    <langue>FR</langue>
    <libellepays>FRANCE</libellepays>
    <loanofhandlingtool>false</loanofhandlingtool>
    <parking>false</parking>
    <reseau>R01</reseau>
    <distributionsort></distributionsort>
    <lotacheminement></lotacheminement>
    <versionplantri></versionplantri>
</listepointretraitacheminement>
<listepointretraitacheminement>
    <accespersonnemobilitereduite>true</accespersonnemobilitereduite>
    <adresse1>34 RUE DU GENERAL DE GAULLE</adresse1>
    <adresse2></adresse2>
    <adresse3></adresse3>
    <codepostal>17139</codepostal>
    <congespartiel>false</congespartiel>
    <congestotal>false</congestotal>
    <coordgeolocalisationlatitude>46.188607</coordgeolocalisationlatitude>
    <coordgeolocalisationlongitude>-1.066762</coordgeolocalisationlongitude>
    <distanceenmetre>8032</distanceenmetre>
    <horairesouverturedimanche>00:00-00:00 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturedimanche>
    <horairesouverturejeudi>09:00-12:00 14:30-16:30</horairesouverturejeudi>
    <horairesouverturelundi>13:30-17:00 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturelundi>
    <horairesouverturemardi>09:00-12:00 13:45-16:30</horairesouverturemardi>
    <horairesouverturemercredi>09:00-12:00 13:45-16:30</horairesouverturemercredi>
    <horairesouverturesamedi>09:00-12:00 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturesamedi>
    <horairesouverturevendredi>09:00-12:00 13:45-16:30</horairesouverturevendredi>
    <identifiant>171420</identifiant>
    <indicedelocalisation></indicedelocalisation>
    <localite>DOMPIERRE SUR MER</localite>
    <nom>BUREAU DE POSTE DOMPIERRE SUR MER BP</nom>
    <periodeactivitehorairedeb>04/11</periodeactivitehorairedeb>
    <periodeactivitehorairefin>31/12</periodeactivitehorairefin>
    <poidsmaxi>20000</poidsmaxi>
    <typedepoint>BPR</typedepoint>
    <codepays>FR</codepays>
    <langue>FR</langue>
    <libellepays>FRANCE</libellepays>
    <loanofhandlingtool>false</loanofhandlingtool>
    <parking>false</parking>
    <reseau>R01</reseau>
    <distributionsort></distributionsort>
    <lotacheminement></lotacheminement>
    <versionplantri></versionplantri>
</listepointretraitacheminement>
<listepointretraitacheminement>
    <accespersonnemobilitereduite>false</accespersonnemobilitereduite>
    <adresse1>1 RUE DE L ADJUDANT GALLAND</adresse1>
    <adresse2></adresse2>
    <adresse3></adresse3>
    <codepostal>17139</codepostal>
    <congespartiel>false</congespartiel>
    <congestotal>false</congestotal>
    <coordgeolocalisationlatitude>46.188404</coordgeolocalisationlatitude>
    <coordgeolocalisationlongitude>-1.068905</coordgeolocalisationlongitude>
    <distanceenmetre>8104</distanceenmetre>
    <horairesouverturedimanche>00:00-00:00 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturedimanche>
    <horairesouverturejeudi>09:00-19:30 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturejeudi>
    <horairesouverturelundi>09:00-19:30 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturelundi>
    <horairesouverturemardi>09:00-19:30 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturemardi>
    <horairesouverturemercredi>09:00-19:30 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturemercredi>
    <horairesouverturesamedi>09:00-19:30 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturesamedi>
    <horairesouverturevendredi>09:00-19:30 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturevendredi>
    <identifiant>999345</identifiant>
    <indicedelocalisation></indicedelocalisation>
    <localite>DOMPIERRE SUR MER</localite>
    <nom>U EXPRESS</nom>
    <periodeactivitehorairedeb>01/01</periodeactivitehorairedeb>
    <periodeactivitehorairefin>31/12</periodeactivitehorairefin>
    <poidsmaxi>20000</poidsmaxi>
    <typedepoint>A2P</typedepoint>
    <codepays>FR</codepays>
    <langue>FR</langue>
    <libellepays>FRANCE</libellepays>
    <loanofhandlingtool>false</loanofhandlingtool>
    <parking>false</parking>
    <reseau>R03</reseau>
    <distributionsort>79T25</distributionsort>
    <lotacheminement>NIT0</lotacheminement>
    <versionplantri>3</versionplantri>
</listepointretraitacheminement>
<listepointretraitacheminement>
    <accespersonnemobilitereduite>true</accespersonnemobilitereduite>
    <adresse1>PLACE DES CHARMILLES</adresse1>
    <adresse2></adresse2>
    <adresse3></adresse3>
    <codepostal>17440</codepostal>
    <congespartiel>false</congespartiel>
    <congestotal>false</congestotal>
    <coordgeolocalisationlatitude>46.133284</coordgeolocalisationlatitude>
    <coordgeolocalisationlongitude>-1.114946</coordgeolocalisationlongitude>
    <distanceenmetre>8114</distanceenmetre>
    <horairesouverturedimanche>00:00-00:00 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturedimanche>
    <horairesouverturejeudi>09:30-12:00 14:30-17:30</horairesouverturejeudi>
    <horairesouverturelundi>09:30-12:00 13:30-17:30</horairesouverturelundi>
    <horairesouverturemardi>09:30-12:00 13:30-17:30</horairesouverturemardi>
    <horairesouverturemercredi>09:30-12:00 13:30-17:30</horairesouverturemercredi>
    <horairesouverturesamedi>09:00-12:00 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturesamedi>
    <horairesouverturevendredi>09:30-12:00 13:30-17:30</horairesouverturevendredi>
    <identifiant>170280</identifiant>
    <indicedelocalisation></indicedelocalisation>
    <localite>AYTRE</localite>
    <nom>BUREAU DE POSTE AYTRE BP</nom>
    <periodeactivitehorairedeb>04/11</periodeactivitehorairedeb>
    <periodeactivitehorairefin>31/12</periodeactivitehorairefin>
    <poidsmaxi>20000</poidsmaxi>
    <typedepoint>BPR</typedepoint>
    <codepays>FR</codepays>
    <langue>FR</langue>
    <libellepays>FRANCE</libellepays>
    <loanofhandlingtool>false</loanofhandlingtool>
    <parking>false</parking>
    <reseau>R01</reseau>
    <distributionsort></distributionsort>
    <lotacheminement></lotacheminement>
    <versionplantri></versionplantri>
</listepointretraitacheminement>
<listepointretraitacheminement>
    <accespersonnemobilitereduite>false</accespersonnemobilitereduite>
    <adresse1>1 RUE LOIC CARADEC</adresse1>
    <adresse2></adresse2>
    <adresse3></adresse3>
    <codepostal>17180</codepostal>
    <congespartiel>false</congespartiel>
    <congestotal>true</congestotal>
    <coordgeolocalisationlatitude>46.159950</coordgeolocalisationlatitude>
    <coordgeolocalisationlongitude>-1.108776</coordgeolocalisationlongitude>
    <distanceenmetre>8402</distanceenmetre>
    <horairesouverturedimanche>00:00-00:00 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturedimanche>
    <horairesouverturejeudi>08:00-19:00 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturejeudi>
    <horairesouverturelundi>08:00-19:00 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturelundi>
    <horairesouverturemardi>08:00-19:00 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturemardi>
    <horairesouverturemercredi>08:00-19:00 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturemercredi>
    <horairesouverturesamedi>08:00-12:00 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturesamedi>
    <horairesouverturevendredi>08:00-19:00 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturevendredi>
    <identifiant>998704</identifiant>
    <indicedelocalisation></indicedelocalisation>
    <listeconges>
        <calendardedebut>2019-11-04T00:00:00+01:00</calendardedebut>
        <calendardefin>2020-05-06T00:00:00+02:00</calendardefin>
        <numero>1</numero>
    </listeconges>
    <localite>PERIGNY</localite>
    <nom>LA POSTE CARREPRO PERIGNY</nom>
    <periodeactivitehorairedeb>01/01</periodeactivitehorairedeb>
    <periodeactivitehorairefin>31/12</periodeactivitehorairefin>
    <poidsmaxi>20000</poidsmaxi>
    <typedepoint>A2P</typedepoint>
    <codepays>FR</codepays>
    <langue>FR</langue>
    <libellepays>FRANCE</libellepays>
    <loanofhandlingtool>false</loanofhandlingtool>
    <parking>false</parking>
    <reseau>R03</reseau>
    <distributionsort>79T21</distributionsort>
    <lotacheminement>NIT0</lotacheminement>
    <versionplantri>3</versionplantri>
</listepointretraitacheminement>
<listepointretraitacheminement>
    <accespersonnemobilitereduite>true</accespersonnemobilitereduite>
    <adresse1>108 BOULEVARD DE LA REPUBLIQUE</adresse1>
    <adresse2></adresse2>
    <adresse3></adresse3>
    <codepostal>17340</codepostal>
    <congespartiel>false</congespartiel>
    <congestotal>false</congestotal>
    <coordgeolocalisationlatitude>46.076423</coordgeolocalisationlatitude>
    <coordgeolocalisationlongitude>-1.09162</coordgeolocalisationlongitude>
    <distanceenmetre>8523</distanceenmetre>
    <horairesouverturedimanche>00:00-00:00 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturedimanche>
    <horairesouverturejeudi>09:00-12:00 14:30-17:30</horairesouverturejeudi>
    <horairesouverturelundi>09:00-12:30 14:00-17:30</horairesouverturelundi>
    <horairesouverturemardi>09:00-12:30 14:00-17:30</horairesouverturemardi>
    <horairesouverturemercredi>09:00-12:30 14:00-17:30</horairesouverturemercredi>
    <horairesouverturesamedi>09:00-12:00 00:00-00:00</horairesouverturesamedi>
    <horairesouverturevendredi>09:00-12:30 14:00-17:30</horairesouverturevendredi>
    <identifiant>170940</identifiant>
    <indicedelocalisation></indicedelocalisation>
    <localite>CHATELAILLON PLAGE</localite>
    <nom>BUREAU DE POSTE CHATELAILLON PLAGE</nom>
    <periodeactivitehorairedeb>04/11</periodeactivitehorairedeb>
    <periodeactivitehorairefin>31/12</periodeactivitehorairefin>
    <poidsmaxi>20000</poidsmaxi>
    <typedepoint>BPR</typedepoint>
    <codepays>FR</codepays>
    <langue>FR</langue>
    <libellepays>FRANCE</libellepays>
    <loanofhandlingtool>false</loanofhandlingtool>
    <parking>false</parking>
    <reseau>R01</reseau>
    <distributionsort></distributionsort>
    <lotacheminement></lotacheminement>
    <versionplantri></versionplantri>
</listepointretraitacheminement>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i think i could replace Js script by jquery script
and it will works.